# How can I replace double and single quotations in a string efficiently?

Tags: python, database, string

I'm parsing a xml file and inserting it into database.
However since some text containes double or single quotation I'm having problem with insertion. Currently I'm using the code shown below. But it seems it's inefficient.

```
s = s.replace('"', ' ')
s = s.replace("'", ' ')
```

Is there any way I can insert text without replacing these quotations?

OR

Is there any efficient way to substitute them efficiently ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why can't you insert strings containing quote marks into your database? Is there some weird data type that permits any character except a quote mark? Or are you building an `insert` statement with literal strings, rather than binding your strings to query parameters as you should be doing?

If you're doing

```
cursor.execute('insert into mytable (somefield) values ("%s")' % (mystring))
```

then that's unsafe and wrong. Instead, you should be doing

```
cursor.execute('insert into mytable (somefield) values (%(myparam)s)',
                dict(myparam=mystring))
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use **`str.translate`** instead of doing two `replace()` calls

```
>>> import string
>>> quotes_to_spaces=string.maketrans('"\'',"  ")
>>> s=s.translate(quotes_to_spaces)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like _mysql.escape_string():

```
>>> import _mysql
>>> a = '''I said, "Don't do that"'''
>>> a
'I said, "Don\'t do that"'
>>> _mysql.escape_string(a)
'I said, \\"Don\\\'t do that\\"'
```

However, the manual recommends using [connection.escape_string()](http://www.mikusa.com/python-mysql-docs/docs/_mysql.html#connection-escape_string), but I think you need a database connection first.